# Textbox has to be cleared when display is none

Tags: html, jquery, input, hide

Users on my site can fill in a form with different subjects. If they fill in one of the subjects and they decide to select another subject the one he was filling in hides. And the other one opens. But when the user selects the same subject he filled in before it is still filled in. What I want to have is when the user decides to select another subject the old one hides AND clear all the information that is in with it. My code is like this but this is very simplified:

```
<div class="steps">
<label for="example">Example</label>
<input type="text" name="inputexample" id="inputexample" />
</div>
```

And, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RSfV4/)

Comment: I can't see any code here, just HTML markup.

Comment: share jsfiddle with problem code

Comment: @MelanciaUK I don't think you'll need it, I just added it so the answers could be based on it so it would be better understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
    var class1=$(this).attr('class');
    $('div').each(function(){
      $('input[type=text]').val('');
      if($(this).attr('id')==class1)
      {
          $(this).show();
      }
      else{
         $(this).hide();
        }
    }); 
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/uPHSr/1/

Comment: I just started working with jQuery, can you base it on my code in the fiddle (that I just added)? Or tell me what to change te make it work?

Comment: Add jquery library in your head section. Include above code inside $(function () {});